# Convert content in .txt file

Tags: windows, shell

I want to convert all the comma ',' inside a text file to pipe delimiter '|' using windows batch command.

[image]

Can someone help me please.

Comment: A global search and replace may be simpler in windows. If you have WSL installed you can simply use `tr ',' '|' < your_file > your_new_file` and `your_new_file` will have pipes instead of commas. You can do it with `sed -i 's/,/|/g' your_file` to edit your file in-place in WSL as well.

Comment: Use Windows `PowerShell` Replace method.